# remove telegram profile photo with telegram-cli or API's

Tags: telegram

i want to make a auto profile changer program with telegram-cli.
i can upload new profile photo with 'set_profile_photo' , but i can't remove old photos.
is there any way to remove old photos with telegram-cli or telegram API ?

Comment: if you are using python and telethon use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58569041/10382054

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the ***current profile photo*** you can use the following:

```
photos.updateProfilePhoto#eef579a0 id:InputPhoto crop:InputPhotoCrop = UserProfilePhoto;
```

Set `id:InputPhoto` to `inputPhotoEmpty#1cd7bf0d` and set `crop:InputPhotoCrop` to `inputPhotoCropAuto#ade6b004`

see below:

```
send_message(TL.photos_updateProfilePhoto(TL.InputPhotoEmpty{}, TL.InputPhotoCropAuto{})
```

Comment: @HamidrezaKavehpishghadam i have updated the answer. sorry i made a mistake in the previous answer. Test this it should work