# Remove telegram profile photo by telethon library or any API

Tags: api, telegram, python-telegram-bot, telethon

I can't delete profile photo by telethon library or any else API

What I already did below (using telethon) but it doesn't work

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync
from telethon.tl.functions.photos import DeletePhotosRequest

api_id = "id"
api_hash = "hash"


client = TelegramClient("bot_5", api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

client(DeletePhotosRequest(client.get_profile_photos('me')))
```

I expected what this code would delete my profile photo

How can I delete it with API?

Comment: This code seems to work correctly. What's doing wrong?

Comment: the line client(DeletePhotosRequest(client.get_profile_photos('me'))) return something like that: <coroutine object UserMethods.__call__ at some_number> and doesn't change my profile photo

Comment: You should make sure you have imported `telethon.sync` in your script, or else you should `await` it yourself. Are you sure the real code has `from telethon import sync`? You can rewrite it as `from telethon.sync import TelegramClient` to make sure nothing removes it.

Comment: Yeah, `from telethon.sync import TelegramClient` works. But what does it mean "you should `await` it"?

Comment: It means you should use `await` before the call. But this shouldn't be necessary if you have `telethon.sync` imported, unless you are working from inside an event handler (which your code doesn't show).

Answer (score 1):

this will work for you

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.photos import DeletePhotosRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPhoto


with TelegramClient('your session', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    p = client.get_profile_photos('me')[0]
    client(DeletePhotosRequest(
        id=[InputPhoto(
            id=p.id,
            access_hash=p.access_hash,
            file_reference=p.file_reference
        )]
    ))
```

- get_profile_photos will return you a list

Comment: It shown the next error: **RuntimeError: You must use "async with" if the event loop is running (i.e. you are inside an "async def")**

Comment: no It's not, I use with statement and telethon.sync module...copy this code and run it i test and worked for me !